# Merge known duplicate

Tags: duplicate-contacts

I have two records for the same person. How do I merge them? I know there is a function to look for possible duplicates but these records are not being picked up because of spelling errors.

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE.

You can merge the contacts manually via search results. Here is a link to the specifics:

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/#merging-contacts-from-search-results

You should also review the information on merging two contacts manually here:

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/#using-rules-and-merging-duplicate-contacts-manually

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to find any 2 contacts via a Search, then select them and click Merge - then look at the URL and substitute the IDs of the 2 contacts you actually want to merge.

The URL will be of this format

/civicrm/contact/merge?reset=1&cid=XXX&oid=YYY

where XXX is the id of the contact that will be retained

and YYY is the ID of the duplicate contact that will go to trash.

Answer (score 3):

Just run a search to get both records to show up in a list, click the two contact line check boxes and use the "actions" drop down for "merge contacts". If you need you can just temporarily change the last name of one of the duplicate records to match the other one to make getting both contacts in one search easier.